# WebView windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm displaying a `WebView`in my app, the `WebView` that I'm showing require the gps position, but for some reason the `WebView` does't retrieve the position.

There is a way to allow the `WebView` to get the position, or some way to pass the position to the `WebView`?

Comment: With "user position" do you mean the gps position?

Comment: yes i mean gps position sorry

Comment: ok. In the web view are you render a real web page from a url address? For example http://www.example.com/mypage ? Do you need to get the gps position from the web page?

Comment: yes, i'm rendering a real web page, i need the web page to get the phone gps position. I'm thinking about injecting the gps position by calling InvokeScriptAsync

Comment: The best technique here is to get the gps position using C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206956(v=vs.105).aspx and inject the gps position with InvokeScriptAsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by injecting some JS to the `WebView` by using this code inside the event `NavigationCompleted`:

```
var geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 500;
geolocator.MovementThreshold = 50;
geolocator.ReportInterval = 1000;

position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

var js = $"var pos = new google.maps.LatLng({position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude}, {position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude});";

await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new List<string>() { js });
```